# Custom annotation not getting argument's value

Tags: java, annotations, spring-aop

Writing this in Spring and trying to use a custom annotation that takes in the value from the method's argument and perform some logic over it.
But it doesn't work. It ends up printing out the String value I passed in rather than the variable's value.

Example the variable is called name and its value is "Dan". When I pass in the argument, it ends up printing out "name" instead of "Dan".
If I were to do the same for a Cacheable annotation in Spring it works fine. Using Intellij and even based on the ide's highlight it seems to recognise the argument when I pass it in for @Cacheable but not the case for my custom annotation. Please advice what I'm doing wrong.

My custom annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomAnnot {
    String key();
}
```

Implementing  annotation. This wrongly prints out "#key" when I am expecting "Dan"

```
@CustomAnnot(key = "#key")
public Object getObj(String key) {
    return null;
}
```

Example passing in same expression for cacheable which works.

```
@Cacheable(key = "#key")
public Object getAnotherObj(String key) {
    return null;
}
```

Believe this code is not causing any issues. Just adding it in case. Using annotation to redirect to an Aspect class where the printing occurs, where I validate it to print wrongly.

```
@Around("@annotation(CustomAnnot)")
public Object get(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, CustomAnnot customAnnot) throws Throwable {
    String key = customAnnot.key();
    System.out.println(key);
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. What is `performMocking.key()`? Did you mean `customAnnot.key()`? Why did you expect that to return anything other than `"#key"` when that's what you assigned to the annotation element `key`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, amended. By passing in #key, I am expecting that to pick up the String key value in the method's parameter. Isn't that the case? It happens for Cacheable.

Comment: Annotations aren't magic. `Cacheable` has an entire library behind it to process annotated methods/classes. Right now you're literally just retrieving what you specified here `@CustomAnnot(key = "#key")`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis What would be the suggestion here. I do need a way for my custom annotation to pick up what my argument value is. Need it to come from the annotation here. Can't be going for any reflection approaches due to other designs in place. Guess attempting a library to address this would be overkill. I wasn't expecting the annotation to work magics but expected the Spel (Expression language) to pick up the argument value. Guess not..

Comment: not quite understanding your case, but if all you want is argument value, do you know you can get it from `pjp.getArgs()` and if you want to compare param name , you can get all param names from `(MethodSignature) pjp.getStaticPart().getSignature().getParameterNames()`

Comment: SpEL is also not "magic". You have to use the engine to parse the value content and interpret it the way you think it is appropriate. This is not trivial. You have to determine that `#key` is pointing to the parameter whose name is `key` (which you can get through reflection from the method's parameters) and then find the corresponding value in the args (as @user3487063 suggests).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I was going for annotation to have flexibility to be able to use any argument in a method or even combine multiple arguments like key = "#arg1+#arg2+#arg3" . Seems not going to be a straight forward implementation then.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is argument's value based on your key , you can do something like this. Exception handling left out.

```
@Around("@annotation(customAnnot)")
  public Object get(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, CustomAnnot customAnnot) throws Throwable {
    MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) pjp.getStaticPart().getSignature();
    List<String> paramsList = Arrays.asList(signature.getParameterNames());
    List<Object> argsList = Arrays.asList(pjp.getArgs());
    String key = customAnnot.key();
    key = key.substring(1);

    logger.info("[{}]", argsList.get(paramsList.indexOf(key)));
    return key;
  }
```

calling

```
test.getObj("Dan");
```

prints:
[Dan]

Comment: Yes but I need flexibility to work with different number of arguments, types and order. Example methodA(String a, String b) where maybe I only want to capture String b. Another methodB(String a, String b, String c) and only want String c here or in another case I need 2 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for isn't possible using annotations alone.  Annotations are processed and embedded in the class byte codes during compilation, at which point in time their presence and their attribute values are fixed.  Any processing of the annotation attribute values would have to be done by a layer above the basic java annotation APIs.